# Python Pulp - Multiple ADP contraints for snake draft

Tags: python, optimization, linear-regression, pulp

I am new to python/pulp and I am trying to replicate an excel solver snake draft problem in python. I have found a couple of python optimizer solutions for dfs.  My model is similar with the exception of instead of a single constraint for salary, I have multiple constraints based on ADP.  For instance, if I am in a 10 team league with the 7th pick and I want to optimize my first 8 picks.  My 1st ADP constraint would be 8 of my picks would have an ADP higher than 6. 2nd constraint would be at least 7 of my picks would have an ADP higher than 13.  3rd - at least 6 picks have an ADP higher than 26 and so forth for 8 rounds.  The suggestion that was made was to make a binary helper column which I have done for each round.  This approach seems cumbersome and is not useful if I want to create a loop for each draft position's optimal lineup. Is there a better way to write the code for the Rnd1 thru the Rnd8 sections of the code.  Thanks

[Fantasy Football Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdUgf.png)

```
availables = players.groupby(["Position", "Rk", "PLAYER", "TEAM", "EPPG", "Rnd1", "Rnd2", 
"Rnd3", "Rnd4", "Rnd5", "Rnd6", "Rnd7", "Rnd8"]).agg('count')
availables = availables.reset_index()

ADPs = {}
points = {}
R1s = {}
R2s = {}
R3s = {}
R4s = {}
R5s = {}
R6s = {}
R7s = {}
R8s = {}
lineups_dict = {}

for pos in availables.Position.unique():
  available_pos = availables[availables.Position == pos]
  point = list(available_pos[['PLAYER', 'EPPG']].set_index("PLAYER").to_dict().values())[0]
  R1 = list(available_pos[['PLAYER', 'Rnd1']].set_index("PLAYER").to_dict().values())[0]
  R2 = list(available_pos[['PLAYER', 'Rnd2']].set_index("PLAYER").to_dict().values())[0]
  R3 = list(available_pos[['PLAYER', 'Rnd3']].set_index("PLAYER").to_dict().values())[0]
  R4 = list(available_pos[['PLAYER', 'Rnd4']].set_index("PLAYER").to_dict().values())[0]
  R5 = list(available_pos[['PLAYER', 'Rnd5']].set_index("PLAYER").to_dict().values())[0]
  R6 = list(available_pos[['PLAYER', 'Rnd6']].set_index("PLAYER").to_dict().values())[0]
  R7 = list(available_pos[['PLAYER', 'Rnd7']].set_index("PLAYER").to_dict().values())[0]
  R8 = list(available_pos[['PLAYER', 'Rnd8']].set_index("PLAYER").to_dict().values())[0]

points[pos] = point
R1s[pos] = R1
R2s[pos] = R2
R3s[pos] = R3
R4s[pos] = R4
R5s[pos] = R5
R6s[pos] = R6
R7s[pos] = R7
R8s[pos] = R8

pos_num_available = {
"QB": 1,
"RB": 3,
"TE": 1,
"WR": 3,
"DEF": 0,
"K": 0
                }

for lineup in range(1,9):
   _vars = {k: LpVariable.dict(k, v, cat='Binary') for k, v in points.items()}

prob = LpProblem("Fantasy", LpMaximize)
rewards = []
Rnd_1 = []
Rnd_2 = []
Rnd_3 = []
Rnd_4 = []
Rnd_5 = []
Rnd_6 = []
Rnd_7 = []
Rnd_8 = []

for k, v in _vars.items():
    rewards += lpSum([points[k][i] * _vars[k][i] for i in v])
    Rnd_1 += lpSum([R1s[k][i] * _vars[k][i] for i in v])
    Rnd_2 += lpSum([R2s[k][i] * _vars[k][i] for i in v])
    Rnd_3 += lpSum([R3s[k][i] * _vars[k][i] for i in v])
    Rnd_4 += lpSum([R4s[k][i] * _vars[k][i] for i in v])
    Rnd_5 += lpSum([R5s[k][i] * _vars[k][i] for i in v])
    Rnd_6 += lpSum([R6s[k][i] * _vars[k][i] for i in v])
    Rnd_7 += lpSum([R7s[k][i] * _vars[k][i] for i in v])
    Rnd_8 += lpSum([R8s[k][i] * _vars[k][i] for i in v])
    prob += lpSum([_vars[k][i] for i in v]) == pos_num_available[k]
    
prob += lpSum(rewards)
prob += Rnd_1 >= 8
prob += Rnd_2 >= 7
prob += Rnd_3 >= 6
prob += Rnd_4 >= 5
prob += Rnd_5 >= 4
prob += Rnd_6 >= 3
prob += Rnd_7 >= 2
prob += Rnd_8 >= 1

if not lineup == 1:
    prob += (lpSum(rewards) <= total_score-0.01)
prob.solve()

score= str(prob.objective)
constraints = [str(const) for const in prob.constraints.values()]
lineupList = []

for v in prob.variables():
    score = score.replace(v.name, str(v.varValue))
    if v.varValue !=0:
      lineupList.append(v.name)
```

[ADP constraint examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Myr.png)

Comment: Can you edit this to clearly focus on the issue you are having.  The context/problem description is unclear.  "ADP" ??  What is it you are trying to do with draft rounds?  What is the intent of `R1`...`R8`?  It looks like you are over-writing them in the loop you have for construction?

Comment: The issue that I have with the current model is that the Columns Rnd1 through Rnd8 are only useful for modeling Draft pick 7 in a 10 team league..  I would like to import the first six columns only (Rk through Std Dev).  The Rk Column is the ADP.  I would like to use the Rk (ADP) column as the basis for my constraint.

Comment: I have added ADP constraint examples as sample.  There would be a set of constraints for each of the 10 draft positions.  In my excel solver I have 1 set of constraints that I loop through 10 times